# IOS 7 LinkedIn share button implementation using oauth2.0 share issue

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, http-post, linkedin-api

I am trying to make a simple application that will share content with LinkedIn,
here i am able to receive the result without any error but the contents are not present in my LinkedIn timeline . Any Help will be Appreciated and this is my code.

```
-(void)JsonPostRequst:(NSData *)jsonRequestData{

Globaltoken  *token_Obj=[Globaltoken  getInstance];

NSString* shareUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?oauth2_access_token=%@",token_Obj.token];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:shareUrl];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setValue:@"x-li-format" forHTTPHeaderField:@"json"];

[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [jsonRequestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[request setHTTPBody: jsonRequestData];

NSError *errorReturned = nil;

NSURLResponse *response =nil;

NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&errorReturned];

if (errorReturned==nil){

    NSLog(@"data =%@",result);

}else{

    NSLog(@"error =%@",errorReturned);

}

}

-(IBAction)linkedInShare:(id)sender {

NSDictionary *json = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:

                        [[NSDictionary alloc]

                         initWithObjectsAndKeys:

                         @"anyone",@"code",nil], @"visibility",

    [[NSDictionary alloc]

                         initWithObjectsAndKeys:

                         @"title",@"title",

@"description",@"Description",

@"submitted-url",@"www.google.com",

@"submitted-image-url",@"http://m3.licdn.com/media/p/3/000/124/1a6/089a29a.png",

nil], @"content",

                        @"comment", @"comment", nil];



if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:json]) {

   NSError *error=nil;

   NSData *jsonData=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:json options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

    if (error==nil && jsonData !=nil) {

        [self JsonPostRequst:jsonData];

    }

}

}
```

Comment: i have solved this using xml instead of json..if some one need help please let me know

Comment: Can you please answer this question with your XML solution?

Answer (score 0):

The Oauth sharer kit is working for me, i just resolved my issue. Make sure the device on which we are testing has the right time set, because the time stamp of 5 minutes ahead is granted by linkedin APIs